# What's a good way to represent CRUD urls that require a parent id to work?

Tags: url

My website deals with states, which contain regions. So there will be a page called `/states` that lists states, and if you click on one, you get `/state/{id}`.

**Note 1**: This is not a REST endpoint, but an actual web page where you view the state info with a nice UI.

**Note 2**: I'm not concerned about the id's in the url. The site is secured with authentication and if you're not allowed to see state 123, you can't. I also don't need the url's to be pretty, like `/state/new-york`.)

---

Suppose you want to view the regions in state 123. The current site does this with a url like `/regions?StateId=123`, but I don't like putting such an important variable in the query string. The best alternative I can think of is `/state/123/regions`. Is this the best/correct way to do it?

---

Similarly, the site handles edits with a url like `/region-edit?RegionId=456`, which probably should become `/region/456/edit`.

But the site handles adds with a url like `/region-edit?RegionId=0&StateId=123`, which I find quite ugly. This page needs to know the parent state under which it's creating the region. How should this be written? `/state/123/region/add`? `/state/123/add-region`?

I'd really like similar url's to work similarly, but this seems hard to arrange, because the region edit page just needs the region id, but the region *add* page needs to know the *parent state* id. I guess I could do `/state/123/region/add` and also `/state/123/region/456/edit`, but that seems really verbose, and still not quite symmetric.

---

I guess I'm looking for a standard naming convention for this kind of hierarchical situation when doing basic CRUD pages. Is there one?

Comment: Why would you mix page operations and pages in the URL? `/state/123` or `/state/123/regions` can perfectly hold old operations. The question is if you need each CRUD to be navigable. I mean, do you need each CRUD to have its own location?

Comment: @Laiv: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "old operations" or "its own location". What I'm asking is: if you have a `/regions` page, but this only makes sense relative to a given state, how should you specify that state? One could use a query string parameter, but these are fundamentally optional, so I'm considering enforcing it in the route with `/state/123/regions`, but I'm not sure that's a good practice.

Comment: Sorry. It's a typo. I meant "all operations". My question was trying to make you think _why do you want to make it contextual?_ In this regard, navigability is important. You reach _regions_ from _states_ (/state/123/regions) but accessing all the regions can make sense too (/regions). And each is likely to support similar query strings to filter the content.  Right? And you will end up with two ways to reach the same content...

Comment: Forget best/common practices (most are opinionable). What fulfils your needs for aesthetics, consistency, readability and future proof? Bearing in mind that URLs are meaningless for human readers. That said, your arguments to change the current navigability from query strings to hierarchical paths is valid! If it's in your hand to do, then is fine. I know cases where you can not change this because the URL is not that meaningless and the source code interprets the URL. In that case, altering the path can be problematic.